# Doxygen - how to end an attention block without newline

Tags: c++, doxygen

Basically I want to continue the flow of the regular text after an attention section. If I leave a newline, doxygen will not associate the text before the newline as the documentation of the item. Is there a general way to end an arbitrary section, such as `@attention`, without putting the whole section (i.e. `@attention`) in another block and terminating it.

**Edit**

For example, given

```
///this is a function
///@attention attention text

///should be outside attention text
void testFunc() {};
```

the doxygen output looks like:

> void testFunc     ()
>
> should be outside attention text
>
> this is a function
>
> Attention:
> attention text

i.e. the order of the text is changed.

**Update**

Another similar problem: in the beginning of a file I have:

```
///@author Somebody
///

#define MY_MACRO printf
```

The author gets associated with the macro, and not the entire file. If I append an empty comment line after the `@author`, I get the same result

Generally, is there an universal way to end a block in doxygen, when there is not an explicit closing macro like `@endcode`.

Comment: Can you post some example code? I don't think your statement "If I leave a newline, doxygen will not associate the text before the newline as the doc of the item" is how things are supposed to work, so some code will greatly help track down the problem.

Comment: In response to your updated question: there is not a general way to end a block unless it is explicitly mentioned in the doxygen manual (like `\endcode`). Usually the range of the commands is given in the documentation, generally denoted by the use of different types brackets. The [`\author`](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/commands.html#cmdauthor) command "ends when a blank line or some other sectioning command is encountered."

Comment: Your `\author` command is being associated with the macro because it is the documnetation block which appears immediately before the macro. The same would apply if the macro were a variable or function - this is how doxygen decides what a particular comment block refers to. If you want to give the author of the file preceed the line with `\author` on it with a [`\file`](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/commands.html#cmdfile) command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
///this is a function
///@attention attention text
///
///should be outside attention text
void testFunc() {};
```

Rather than leaving blank lines within your documentation block keep them all together. The attention command ends with a blank line, but that blank line is expected to be part of the documentation block (i.e. a blank line means `///` on its own).

Alternatively, you could use the `/** */` style of comments, and then you would write

```
/** this is a function
    @attention attention text

    should be outside attention text
*/
void testFunc() {};
```

Comment: Ah! I thought I had tried this, but apparently I haven't. It works, thanks. I appended a generalization to my question (because I have a similar problem with @author), could you have a look please?

Answer (score 2):

> The author gets associated with the macro, and not the entire file.

If you wanted it associated with the file, then you should associate it with the *file*. This means using the `@file` specifier in the same block as the `@author` (and before it, obviously).